# Behaviour of domains when transferred, that do not use auth codes

Tags: domains, dns, domain-transfer

I am currently working on a feature for an existing project that enables the user to initiate a transfer out of domains. As stated by [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oVNszsvqhxh3hlT1LYMfcwq3lw_e6J7DeBePvN4t2aw/edit#gid=1203932299) Google Spreadsheet, which is I hope somewhat correct, most TLDs do in fact use auth codes. The API I am working with has a property in the domain object called `TransferLockEnabled`. This is a non-required property when working with a domain and controls, as semantically obvious, if a domain can be transferred or not.

So at the moment I can easily set this to `false` which in the response object provides me with an auth code. So for domains that use an auth code it works just fine.

Problem is, if a TLD doesn't use auth codes, for example .uk, I am not aware of what happens in the backend. To my little knowledge it triggers an email being sent to either the admin or the owner handle of the domain (or both).

I am somewhat familiar with the domain name system, but not much more than any other web developer, so I'd appreciate any help.

How do domains, that don't use an auth code, behave when initiating a transfer out. Does someone just start a transfer in and that triggers an email, etc., being sent? How does it differ from other domains?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How domains, that don't use an auth code, behave when initiating a transfer out. Does someone just start a transfer in and that triggers an email, etc., being sent? How does it differ from other domains?

Comment: Add that to the original question and it then becomes answerable and may be the question will be taken off hold.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: So is this closed for good?